# How to get the max Y coordinate of multiple views

Tags: objective-c

If I have n number of views inside a container / parent view how can I check if any of the subviews extend over the parent view?

If I had 1 subview I could do the following
CGRectGetMaxY(subView.frame) > CGRectGetMaxY(containerView.bounds)

Comment: Iterate over all the subviews and do just that?

Comment: Ok so no shortcut get max y in array?

Answer (score 0):

NSArray has some pretty cool stuff built in to get the things like the average/max/etc values from an array. What you want to do is this:

```
NSNumber *maxY = [subviewArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.maxY"];
```

However, it won't work since `UIView` doesn't have a maxY property by default. But don't fret! We can just add it ourselves by extending UIView:

```
// UIView+Extensions.h
@interface UIView(Extensions)

- (CGFloat)maxY;

@end

// UIView+Extensions.m
@implementation UIView(Extensions)

- (CGFloat)maxY
{
    return CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame);
}

@end
```

Now you can safely use `[subviewArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.maxY"];` to get the max Y value of all subviews.